# How to format table's borders so they don't span through the entire table?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, border

My table looks like this:

[image: My table whose borders span through the entire table]

But I need for it to look like this example:

[image: ![Example table whose borders stop before the end of the table]

They look fairly similar but if you look closely you will see that in the example the borders stop before they reach the end of the table, but they reach the end of the table in my table.

I need the borders to **not** reach the end of the table.

Here's the link to my Word document if it'll help: https://www.mediafire.com/file/s18uon3i0ajs8dn/517_natipkano.docx/file

Comment: Insert a dummy column at the left and right of your table and style their borders as required.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Although, I had to do some additional work before it worked because when I added dummy columns, the table's size increased drastically and it went of screen since the document is in two columns. I had to copy/paste the table in another document, edit it there and then paste it back. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can check it as a solution to my problem?

Comment: Answer added as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I need the borders to not reach the end of the table

You can insert a dummy column at the left and right of your table and style their borders as required.